# Android update ticker text of Foreground Service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have service that I've used `startForeground()` method with a `Notification`.

i'm saving an instance of my `Notification` in order to update it easily.

there was no problem updating any of the field in it, but when i'm updating the ticker text and notifying the `NotifcationManager` about the change - it doesn't show my new ticker.

Is it event possible to update the `Notification's` ticker text of a foreground `Service's Notification` ?
Is so - any idea why isn't it updating and showing the new ticker on screen ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that feels funny.

I can call `Service.stopForeground(true)`;

followed by `Service.startForeground(myNotificationId, myNotification)` with the notification with the new ticker and it does the trick but it doesn't make sense..